# Too few arguments to function in livewire component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

1.First create an event the blade component

```js
reserveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $wire.dispatch('make-reservation', { time: time });
});
```

2.Second listen for the event in the livewire class:

```php
#[On('make-reservation')]
public function saveReservation($time)
{
    return redirect('/test')->with('time', $time);
}
```

3.You will face "Too few arguments to function

> `App\Livewire\ReserveAppointment::saveReservation()`, 0 passed in" error.

This is weird!

Comment: I've tested your code and it works perfectly for me. In which context do you add *reserveButton.addEventListener(...)* ?

Answer (score -1):

Adjust your saveReservation method to expect an array and then extract the time from this array

```
#[On('make-reservation')]
public function saveReservation($data)
{
    $time = $data['time'];
    return redirect('/test')->with('time', $time);
}
```